# ComplexHeatmap: Increase label size of side annotation?

Tags: r

Hi is there a way to increase the font size of the label for each of the annotation? 
I tried using gpar setting the fontsize but does'nt seem to be effecting it.  For example using the example in the vignette.

```
    ha = HeatmapAnnotation(foo = anno_barplot(matrix(nc = 2, c(1:10, 10:1))) 
, gp = gpar(fontsize=20)  )
```

What I essentially want is to have foo labeled with font size 20

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The parameter to control that is `annotation_name_gp= gpar(fontsize = 20)`.
Reproducible example:

```r
library(ComplexHeatmap)
set.seed(123)
mat = matrix(rnorm(100), 10)
rownames(mat) = paste0("R", 1:10)
colnames(mat) = paste0("C", 1:10)
column_ha = HeatmapAnnotation(foo1 = runif(10), bar1 = anno_barplot(runif(10)),
                              annotation_name_gp= gpar(fontsize = 20))
row_ha = rowAnnotation(foo2 = runif(10), bar2 = anno_barplot(runif(10)))
Heatmap(mat, name = "mat", top_annotation = column_ha, right_annotation = row_ha)
```

[image]

Comment: This is awesome. Just curious how did you figure the option? I tried looking over the manual and even the function itself but did not see it.  Thanks.

Comment: great thanks. I was looking at ?anno_barplot but now that you show me it makes sense to go up one level.

Comment: Is there a way to change size of the annotation axis values too?

Comment: @Nate, yes, there is; check `??anno_barplot`. E.g. for rowAnnotation you could use with my example above: `row_ha = rowAnnotation(foo2 = runif(10), bar2 = anno_barplot(runif(10), 
    axis_param=list(gp=gpar(fontsize = 14))), width = unit(3, "cm"))` (define font size and increase the width of the barplot in this example).